# How can I replace some characters with `'` character in a text file using sed?

Tags: linux, sed, terminal

this is the command I know `sed -i 's/&#39/'/g' output.txt`. As I figured out that the second `'` character is the cause of unexpected result here. Please tell me how to replace characters with a `'` in a text file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you use double quotes?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr because you should never enclose any script in double quotes. Always use single quotes around any script and additional single quotes within it around only the segments where you need to make part of it accessible for the shell to interpret.

Comment: Yes for those that accept user input. In this case, this is a misplaced claim.

Comment: `echo '$20' | sed "s/$20/$30/"` outputs `$20`. `echo '$2' | sed "s/$2/$30/"` outputs `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression`
No user input involved, just undesirable evaluation by the shell courtesy of the double quotes. Just don't do it and avoid any surprises or the need to add complexity to your scripts. By comparison `echo '$20' | sed 's/$20/$30/'` and `echo '$2' | sed 's/$2/$30/'` both output `$30`, no surprises or need to escape anything the shell might decide to interpret. Feel free to ignore this advice of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/whatever/'\''/g' file
```

..

Comment: Thank you Sir @EdMorton.